# Control IPython Notebook layout of plots and other output

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When an IPython notebook has code in a cell like this:

```
display_html(HTML('Heading'))
plt.plot(x,y)
display_hmtl(HTML('Sub-heading'))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

The output from the plots is always collected at the end, like

```
Heading
Heading
[first plot]
[second plot]
```

How can the layout be controlled so the output is correctly interleaved?

(I know I can put the code in separate cells, but I want to generate long reports by calling blocks of code iteratively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also actively display the figures, instead of having IPython collecting the outputs and displaying it as a result. You should also close all active figures at the end, because for as far as i know, IPython will always display them (again) if they're still open.

For example:

```
display_html(HTML('Heading'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(100),np.random.randn(100).cumsum())
display(fig)

display_html(HTML('Sub-heading'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(100),np.random.randn(100).cumsum())
display(fig)

plt.close('all') # this closes all of them
```

Looks like:

[image]